# RDP inside VMware fusion doesn't get keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, vmware-fusion

#### Setup:

Host: MBP running OS X 10.11.5
VMware: Fusion 8.1.1 (3771013)
Guest OS: Windows 10 or Server 2016 TP5 so far

I have the VMware guest running in full screen using the VMware UI. Inside the guest, I use Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection (mstsc.exe) to connect to another Windows 10 system.

#### Issue:

alt(option)-tab works fine on the guest itself, I can switch between apps that aren't RDC.

If I open an RDC connection that is NOT full screen, alt-tab switches between guest windows; treating the RDC window as another app.

If I open an RDC connection in full screen, alt-tab is completely and silently lost. It doesn't switch apps windows in the guest OS, nor in the RDC session.

I've tried alt-FN-arrows which are Home, End, Page-Up, Page-Down, but they also fail to do anything noticeable.

Is there a setting I missed somewhere to get the keys passed through to RDC connections, or an alternative key to switch apps inside the session?

#### Note:

If I manually RDP into the VMWare guest, then run mstsc inside the guest, all the keys work as expected. This is definitely a VMWare issue, not configuration in the guest OS.

Comment: short answer, no - any key command which can be interpreted first by your native OS... will be.

Comment: @Tetsujin Then how does the guest itself register alt-tab? It's only in the RDP session inside the guest that does nothing

Comment: Sorry, in this case it's the VM that is 'native' - it's an RDC issue. Apple RD does the same as MS. I have to change some of my own key commands so others' work.

Answer (score 2):

This plagued me for months. What worked for me was to disable all key combinations.

**Steps:**

Virtual Machine > Settings > Keyboard & Mouse:

1. Key Mappings uncheck "Enable Key Mappings" and "Enabled Language Specific Key Mappings".
2. Mac Host Shortcuts uncheck "Enable Mac OS Host Keyboard Shortcuts".
3. Fusion Shortcuts uncheck everything you can.  "Ungrab Mouse and Keyboard" is greyed out and will still be checked.

Maybe an ignorant workaround but I can now work efficiently with Alt-Tab window switching and use line breaks in an Excel cell.  I don't think I used any of the key combos.  If there any key combinations I miss, I'll enable that one specifically and see if Alt-Tab still works.

If you to edit this answer, you could binary search and narrow down the problem.

**Setup:**

- Host: MBP running macOS 10.14.6
- VMware: Fusion 11.1.1 (14328561)
- Guest OS: Windows 10 version 1803 RDPing to Windows 10 version 1809.

I have the VMware guest running in full screen using the VMware UI. Inside the guest, I use Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection (mstsc.exe) to connect to another Windows 10 system in full screen.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the RDC application (mstsc.exe), go the the *Local Resources* tab and change the settings highlighted here:

[image: RDC Local Resources keyboard settings]

Comment: Changing this did nothing that I can see. alt-tab is still apparently ignored when the RDC window is focused.

Comment: That's the only thing I could think of to try.  Sorry, buddy.